# PHP - Text Field value based on selected value from List Box

Tags: php

may I know how can I setting the text field's value according to the selected value from List box?

[Table in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ev02.png)

[HTML form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyuW1.png)

For example:
If I choose "DIP" from the List Box then the Text Field will display "Diploma in Information Technology (Programming)" automatically since I setting the Text Field became disabled.

P/S: List Box function was done. I just need some guides to settle the Text Field

Comment: Do you have the full form text inside the selectbox value? I mean like this?

<option value = 'Diploma in Information Technology (Programming)'>DIP</option>

Comment: Nope.. I'm using while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result) to do the looping to display all the programme_code in List Box

Comment: you can do it using javascript/jquery. just load your data only once and on change drop down change value of text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var code = $('#code').val();
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     data: {code: code},
     url: 'get_name_list.php',
     success: function(data) {
        $('#text_field').val(data);
     }
```

in `get_name_list.php` make a query for fetch program_name and return its value. you can get code from `$_POST['code']`. and in success you need to set value for that textbox.

Comment: Its not good way for a small piece of code to use ajax. it can be done by javascript/jquery.

Comment: How can we use without  Ajax because we need to find its appropriate value for that code. so need to use Ajax without page refresh. or we can be use using local-storage in jQuery/JavaScript but that was not good way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Javascript/Jquery. Take idea from this.

Example :

```
1.) $ProgInfo is array of prog_code and prog_name.
2.) On change dropdown call below function with parameter (prog_code) 
3.) getProgName will return you prog_name
```

**Javascript function :**

```
function getProgName(prog_code=null){
        var json_user = <?=json_encode($ProgInfo)?>;
        if(json_user.hasOwnProperty(prog_code)){
            return json_user[prog_code];
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

$('id or class of name').html(getProgName("Your prog_code"));
```